Random walk on stock market
This is a question I got in a quant finance interview: Imagine that that the stock price follows random walk: it rises/falls by 1 with equal probability. You follow trading strategy when you buy a stock If the previous day return is positive, and otherwise sell one stock. you do that for n periods and then you close your position based on the final price. The question is what is the distribution of the pnl of such strategy.
Here is what I tried: Define $x_1=1$ or $0$ with equal probability, and $y_i = 2x_i-1$ is day $i$'s price. The final pnl comes from two parts: final position and the buy/sell cost from such strategy. Further define $s_i=\sum_{j=0}^{i}y_i$. I am able to write the final pnl as $pnl_n=s_{n-1}y_n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_{i-1}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}y_j$. I can proceed further to reduce this pnl a little bit but I do not see a clear way to derive the exact distribution

Hint: UD and DU both lead to losing a dollar and no net stock position change. Hence show that the profit is only dependent on the final price, and independent of the exact path taken. $\quad$ Then, for each price, determine the probability and profit level. Hence we are done.

Well UD or DU does not lead to position change but buying or selling stocks costs money

Side note: If you consider the counter-party's position, then you might recognize the situation as arbitraging supply/demand imbalance on a security which theoretically should have price 0, and they sell/buy a stock for every dollar increase/decrease. $\quad$ This obviously has been well studied (EG They will make money unless the stock price moved significantly. You have the opposite position.)

No I mean if only two days, say UD. At the end of day 1 we buy it costs 1 and at the end of day 2, we have pnl = -1 +0 = -1. So it does not only depends on the final price?

Ah, I made the simplifying assumption that you transacted at the end of the day, rather than at the start of the next day, so as to avoid end effects. (Put alternatively, consider any UD/DU that is in the middle of the sequence, not at the very end) $\quad$ And if it's at the end of the sequence, you may assume that you zeroed out your stock at the final price to evaluate your portfolio. So nothing needs to change.

First observation, this is a zero-sum game.  Your expected p+l is zero.
Suppose the price increases every day for n days in a row.
You owe no shares on day 0.
On day 1, the price goes up 1, you buy one share, your p+l is still 0.
On day 2, the price goes up, you buy a second share, gain 1 on the share you own.  Your p+l is 1.
On day 3, the price goes up, you buy a 3rd share, gain 2 on the shares you own, your net p+l is 3.
On day $n$ your p+l is $1+2+3+4+\cdots + (n-1) = \frac {n(n-1)}{2}$
The likelihood of this happening is $\frac {1}{2^n}$
Next, consider what happens if the share price bounces up and down on alternating days.  You buy a share, the following day the price falls, you sell your share, you lose a dollar.  You lose a dollar every two days.
Question, If the price has risen on $n-1$ days and fallen on $1$ day does your $p+l$ depend on the path taken?  I will leave that to you to prove, but no it doesn't.  We can say you are down a dollar on day 2, and then you have make the same profit for the run-up on the remaining n-2 days.
Your p+l is $\frac {(n-2)(n-3)}{2} - 1 = \frac {(n-1)(n-4)}{2}$
If the price has risen on $n-2$ days and fallen on $2$ days.
p+l $=\frac {(n-4)(n-5)}{2} - 2 = \frac {(n-2)(n-7)}{2}$
Do we have a pattern?
By induction, show that if the price goes up $k$ days and down $n-k$ days
p+l $=\frac {(n-k)(n-3k-1)}{2}$ and happens with probability $\frac {{n\choose k}}{2^n}$

Could you elaborate on the intuitions that why the sequence does not but only the number of up days and down days matters?
